# Suppress log entry for single sudo commands

Tags: linux, unix, sudo, syslog

For server monitoring, we execute couple of commands with password-less `sudo` every minute. This fills the server logs.

> sudo:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/foo/bar

Can I prevent these entries? The options `NOLOG_INPUT` and `NOLOG_OUTPUT` don't look like what I want.

I don't want to omit `sudo`'s logging completely, only for the one user and the one (or more) command.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can disable the logging on a user basis using the `Defaults:` directive

example (disabled logging for user bla)

```
Defaults:bla !syslog
```

or using a `Cmnd_Alias` to disable it per command(s)

```
Cmnd_Alias SCRIPT = /usr/local/bin/myscript
Defaults!SCRIPT !syslog
# multiple commands need a comma between them
Cmnd_Alias MORE = /bin/ls, /bin/cat
Defaults!MORE !syslog
```

Tested on Debian 6.0.6 with `sudo` version `1.7.4p4` (so rather old ;) )

Comment: If someone wants to disable "session opened/closed for user root" messages too, this worked for me:
Defaults!SCRIPT !syslog, !pam_session

Comment: Replace `!syslog` with `!log_allowed` to stop logging successful attempts only, still logging denied attemps.